# How to render multiple indexes of same object efficiently in react without using react components

Tags: reactjs

How to render multiple indexes of same object   efficiently in react without using react components.
Object is having multiple elements and each object is having same set of fields and validation.How to make it distinct so that value or validation wont repeat or overlap.I am new to react ,Please help.

Comment: Can you please show what you already tried?

Comment: Ciao could you provide an example? Like what do you have and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: use codeSandBox if you can

Comment: scenario is ,I have an object inside which I have list of model which is having different set  of fields.On UI ,there is a button called "add section " on click which ,first validation of all fields will happen and then in list of models,new model will be added  . I need to show the valdiation below particular field of every model. i have a validation type for each field.Since I am already new iterating models,i can not iterate valdaition for each field as well,I am getting too many rerender error.So somehow I need to pass errors for each index within iteration of modal. can i use 2D array.